# New series for $\zeta(5)$ involving second-order harmonic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function, combinatorial-identities

In 1997 T. Amdeberhan and D. Zeilberger proved that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(205k^2-160k+32)}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}=-2\zeta(3).\tag{1}$$
In 2008 J. Guillera obtained that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(10k^2-6k+1)(-256)^k}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}=-28\zeta(3).\tag{2}$$
Recently K. C. Au [[arXiv:2212.02986](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.02986)] confirmed the identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(28k^2-18k+3)(-64)^k}{k^5\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}=-14\zeta(3)\tag{3}$$
conjectured by me in 2010.

Motivated by $(1)-(3)$, [my recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07238) and [Question 436205](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436205), I made the following conjecture on new series for $\zeta(5)$ involving second-order harmonic numbers
$$H_n^{(2)}:=\sum_{0<k\le n}\frac1{k^2}\ \ \ \ (n=0,1,2,3,\ldots).$$

**Conjecture 1.** We have
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k((205k^2-160k+32)(4H_{2k-1}^{(2)}-12H_{k-1}^{(2)})-43)}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}&=-8\zeta(5),\tag4
\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-256)^k((10k^2-6k+1)(4H_{2k-1}^{(2)}-3H_{k-1}^{(2)})-2)}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}&=-124\zeta(5),\tag5
\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-64)^k((28k^2-18k+3)(2H_{2k-1}^{(2)}-3H_{k-1}^{(2)})-2)}{k^5\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}&=-31\zeta(5).\tag6
\end{align}

**Remark.** In the same spirit, motivated by the known identities
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(20k^2+8k+1)\frac{\binom{2k}k^5}{(-4096)^k}&=\frac 8{\pi^2},\tag7
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty(74k^2+27k+3)\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}{4096^k}&=\frac{48}{\pi^2},\tag8
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty(120k^2+34k+3)\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{4k}{2k}}{2^{16k}}&=\frac{32}{\pi^2}\tag{9}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty(820k^2+180k+13)\frac{\binom{2k}k^5}{(-2^{20})^k}&=\frac{128}{\pi^2}\tag{10}
\end{align}
(cf. [arXiv:2101.12592](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.12592)), we conjecture the identities
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^5}{(-4096)^k}((20k^2+8k+1)(8H_{2k}^{(2)}-3H_k^{(2)})+4)&=\frac 83,\tag{11}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}{4096^k}((74k^2+27k+3)(92H_{2k}^{(2)}-33H_k^{(2)})+112)&=272,\tag{12}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{4k}{2k}}{2^{16k}}((120k^2+34k+3)(23H_{2k}^{(2)}-7H_k^{(2)})+24)&=\frac{88}3.\tag{13}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^5}{(-2^{20})^k}((820k^2+180k+13)(11H_{2k}^{(2)}-3H_k^{(2)})+43)&=\frac{128}3.\tag{14}
\end{align}

Motivated by $(7)-(9)$ and [Question 436205](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436205), we also formulate the following conjecture on series for $(\log 2)/\pi^2$ involving the harmonic numbers $H_n=\sum_{0<k\le n}\frac 1k\ (n=0,1,2,\ldots)$.

**Conjecture 2.** We have
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^5}{(-4096)^k}((20k^2+8k+1)(15H_{2k}-5H_k)+2)&=\frac{16\log2}{\pi^2},\tag{15}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}{4096^k}((74k^2+27k+3)(51H_{3k}+250H_{2k}-153H_k)+15)&=\frac{9792\log2}{\pi^2},\tag{16}
\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^4\binom{4k}{2k}}{2^{16k}}((120k^2+34k+3)(34H_{4k}+4H_{2k}-8H_k)+19)&=\frac{512\log2}{\pi^2}.\tag{17}
\end{align}

Actually we have many other similar conjectural series.

**QUESTION.** Are the identities $(4)-(6)$ and $(11)-(17)$ true? Can one find a way to prove some of them?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Similarly, I also conjecture the identities \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k((205k^2-160k+32)(H_{2k-1}-H_{k-1})-41k+16)}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}&=\frac{\pi^4}{60},\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-256)^k}{k^5\binom{2k}k^5}((10k^2-6k+1)(2H_{2k-1}-H_{k-1})-3k+1)&=-\frac{\pi^4}2,\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-64)^k}{k^5\binom{2k}k^4\binom{3k}k}((28k^2-18k+3)(4H_{2k-1}-3H_{k-1})-20k+6)&=\frac{\pi^4}2,\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^7}{2^{20k}}((168k^3+76k^2+14k+1)(16H_{2k}^{(2)}-5H_k^{(2)})+8(6k+1))&=\frac{80}{3\pi},\end{align} where $H_n$ denotes the harmonic number $\sum_{0<k\le n}\ \frac1k$.

Comment: Many of these series and similar ones are proven in arXiv:2312.14051